# Is it ok to get negative Cosine Similarity using LSA?

Tags: machine-learning, computational-statistics, information-retrieval, latent-semantic-analysis

I am getting negative cosine similarity value between two documents in Latent Semantic analysis. How should it be treated?

Comment: After applying LSA the cosine similarity should yield values between -1 and 1. Why exactly is this a problem for you? See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68194/computing-document-similarity-in-latent-semantic-analysis "this answer") for a good explanation regarding your question.

Comment: Cosine similarities could be negative for sure. If you're trying to interpret this (not that you think it's problematic to have negative values), then I think it means these two documents are talking about opposite things.

Comment: Same question on SO: [Why can cosine similarity between two vectors be negative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597005/why-can-cosine-similarity-between-two-vectors-be-negative)

Comment: Cosine similarity takes values between -1 and 1, so it's completely ordinary to have negative cosine similarity. Can you [edit] to clarify what problem a negative cosine similarity presents for how you are "treating" your data?